# Scroll to props.location.hash using useEffect after component mounts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a glossary page where each term has it's own card that is not expanded by default. Each card uses the term as it's ID because they will all be unique. I want to support direct links to a specific term via URL hash.

So, if the URL is localhost:3000/#/glossary#Actor, the initial load will scroll to the term and 'open' the card by simulating the click on the element (click handler on that element opens the card).

It is working, but too frequently. Every time I enter text into the search bar or cause a render in any way, it re-scrolls and does the card open animation again. I just want to initially scroll to the term if there is a hash, then ignore it unless it changes.

It only works if I don't include a dep array. If I include a dep array with props.location.hash, the el returns as null and nothing happens. I'm aware that the restarting of the effect is happening because of no dep array, but I don't know why it doesn't work when I add it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //looks for hash in URL; gets element associated with the hash
    let el = document.getElementById(decodeURI(props.location.hash.slice(1)));
    console.log(el)

    //if element exists, get coords and offset for header before scrolling
    if (el) {
      const yCoordinate = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
      const yOffset = -80; 

      window.scrollTo({
          top: yCoordinate + yOffset,
          behavior: 'smooth'
      });

      //opens the card only if not already open
      if (!el.classList.contains('openTermCard')) {
        el.click();
      }
    }
  })
```

useEffect may not be the correct method. I might not even need a hook for this, idk. I just want this initial scroll event to happen on page load and not again.

Comment: have you tried `[]` for your dep array? That's the normal way to do something once on mount.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that as well, and it says props.location.hash is a missing dep when I do. Just returns null for el. I think it's a timing issue between the elements being there and looking for it, but I'm confused why it doesn't work with props.location.hash as a dep.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to figure out a solution without a working sandbox.

From your description, it seems to me your component is rendering more than once on the first load. If you put `[]` as dependency array, the effect only runs once, when the element is not defined yet (hence why you get `null`) and that's why it doesn't work.

One way to go about it is to think what else you can do in terms of designing your app. You mention that every time your component updates it focuses the card again, but that's kind of what you expect when you're using `useEffect`. Is it possible to re-structure the component so that the parent (the one with this side effect) doesn't re-render as often?

If you can provide a code sandbox I'm sure I (and probably others) will be able to help you further.

Comment: Apologies for not having a sandbox. It's proxied on my work computer and there would be a lot needed to make it work the same. If you were trying to achieve the same effect, would you even use useEffect? Like you said, it makes sense why it's happening, I haven't thought of an alternative route yet. I am using the Collapse component from reactstrap on the cards, so each card has it's own expanded state that gets toggled on click. I essentially need the effect in the react version of document onload, I just don't know what that looks like.